# Parse-Server cloud code can't create Role

Tags: parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I have a class called Project for which I create a Parse.Role for read/write permissions.

Here's how I create my Role:

```
var roleName = "hasSound_" + ident;
var projectRole = new Parse.Role(roleName, new Parse.ACL());
projectRole.getUsers().add(creator); 

return projectRole.save().then(function(role) {

var acl = new Parse.ACL();
acl.setReadAccess(role, true); //give read access to Role
acl.setWriteAccess(role, true); //give write access to Role

project.setACL(acl);            
project.save();
```

});

And here's the bad request I'm getting when trying to create the Parse.Role:

```
Mar 04 14:39:32 ancient-lake-41070 heroku/router:  at=info method=POST path="/parse/classes/_Role" host=ancient-lake-41070.herokuapp.com request_id=82af3849-842a-406f-8a4b-5f573e08a1e1 fwd="54.145.36.110" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=400 bytes=578
```

Comment: For some reason adding the `masterKey:true` seems to work: `return projectRole.save({}, { useMasterKey: true} ).then(function(role) {...`

Comment: I take that back. The role is now being created, but it's not being attached to the Project. The Project shows public read + write.

Comment: Does `project.save().then(null, function(err) {console.log(err)})` give you any useful error message?

Comment: Actually I figured it out. Apparently I just had to add `useMasterKey: true` to all my `save()' and now it works: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/37

Comment: Sweet! Make sure you write that in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently I needed to add `useMasterKey` to all my save functions. In a `.save()` function it is the second parameter, like so: `obj.save(null, {useMasterKey: true})`

Once I did that, the Role was created, all my relations are working again, etc.

See here for more info: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/37